# Database logic for conversation (like Forum) PHP, MySql

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, chat, forum

I want create a page where is possible create topics and users are able to comment.

I create the table discussion with a recursive relation.
I don't if the idea is good.

How can I find the id of the parent when a user comment?
I don't if is clear...

Below you will find 3 screenshots to explain you better the situation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify. Are you trying to find the parent comment or the parent topic when a user replies?

Comment: Sorry..
By the way is just 2 levels.
I can't comment to a comment.

When a user comment a topic I don't what parentId put on INSERT code of the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I would not have the parentID point to the comment that precedes it, that's bad practice all around. The parentID should point to the topic and then when selecting all comments from the database, make a query that orders them by time or their ID to see what order they were posted in.

For example...

```
SELECT * FROM `discussion` WHERE `parentID` = 1 ORDER BY `time` DESC;
```

The parentID should be null for topics and not null (integer) for replies (the integer should point to the ID of the topic). I hope I understood what you were asking correctly.

Comment: Ok.
So...

Example:
Topic (id = 5, parentId = null)
  - Comment (id = 6, parentId = 5)
  - Comment (id = 7, parentId = 5)
  - Comment (id = 8, parentId = 5)
  - New comment (Now, when a user reply, I take data from the form with $_POST.

But I don't understand, how I can take the parentId for the new comment (5).

Comment: What do you mean by "how I can take the parentId for the new comment"

Comment: When a user insert a new comment, I have to set the parentId (of the topic).
I don't know how to find the parentId.

Comment: When you create the comment form add a hidden field with a name of "parentID" or something and set the value to that. Then use $_GET or $_POST to read the parentID for when you create the comment.

Comment: Ok, but probably I'll have more topics.
So how I can know what topic (and its id) that the user will reply?